# TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null - puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm starting to have fun with puppeteer, but quite often I come across this mistake. Is there any way to avoid this error and to return the result of all values that are not null ? Sometimes this code works and sometimes it doesn't, and I don't know how to avoid it

```
const test = await page.evaluate(() =>
        Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(.div)).map((a) => ({
        
            result: a.querySelector('.any-div').textContent.trim()
        }))
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
const test = await page.evaluate(() =>
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(.div)).map((a) => ({
    
        result: a.querySelector('.any-div') && a.querySelector('.any-div').textContent.trim()
    }))
);
```

Comment: thank you - it works. For better coding for the future - is it best to have "null" in the results or is it better to have an empty space there?

Comment: In js both are falsy values. you can use any, but handle them accordingly while you display. I personally use empty space so that the data type is consistent.